# Anonymous class is not abstract and does not override (Android + Retrofit)

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am trying to make a Google map show nearby places using retrofit following [this tutorial](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-nearby-places-api-using-retrofit-android/).

I get this error:

> Error:(158, 46) error:  is not abstract and does not
>   override abstract method onFailure(Call,Throwable) in
>   Callback
>
> Error:(159, 13) error: method does not override or implement a method
>   from a supertype

I tried to implement methods using the alt + enter, but it gets different from the tutorial, and it messes up the code.

Here is my main (it's the same from the tutorial)

MapsActivity.java

```
package example.googlemapsapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.HashMap;

import example.googlemapsapp.POJO.Example;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 10000;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }

        //show error dialog if Google Play Services not available
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            Log.d("onCreate", "Google Play Services not available. Ending Test case.");
            finish();
        }
        else {
            Log.d("onCreate", "Google Play Services available. Continuing.");
        }

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
                googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                        0).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        Button btnRestaurant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRestaurant);
        btnRestaurant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                build_retrofit_and_get_response("restaurant");
            }
        });

        Button btnHospital = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHospital);
        btnHospital.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                build_retrofit_and_get_response("hospital");
            }
        });

        Button btnSchool = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSchool);
        btnSchool.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                build_retrofit_and_get_response("school");
            }
        });
    }

    private void build_retrofit_and_get_response(String type) {

        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/";

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitMaps service = retrofit.create(RetrofitMaps.class);

        Call<Example> call = service.getNearbyPlaces(type, latitude + "," + longitude, PROXIMITY_RADIUS);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Example> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

                try {
                    mMap.clear();
                    // This loop will go through all the results and add marker on each location.
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getResults().size(); i++) {
                        Double lat = response.body().getResults().get(i).getGeometry().getLocation().getLat();
                        Double lng = response.body().getResults().get(i).getGeometry().getLocation().getLng();
                        String placeName = response.body().getResults().get(i).getName();
                        String vicinity = response.body().getResults().get(i).getVicinity();
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                        // Position of Marker on Map
                        markerOptions.position(latLng);
                        // Adding Title to the Marker
                        markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);
                        // Adding Marker to the Camera.
                        Marker m = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                        // Adding colour to the marker
                        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                        // move map camera
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
            }
        });

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "entered");

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        //Place current location marker
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");

        // Adding colour to the marker
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));

        // Adding Marker to the Map
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        Log.d("onLocationChanged", String.format("latitude:%.3f longitude:%.3f", latitude, longitude));

        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Exit");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted. Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
            // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The signature of `onResponse`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Callback.html) differs from what you have.

You have:

```
public void onResponse( Response<Example> response, Retrofit retrofit)
```

It should be:

```
public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response)
```

Your `onFailure` also needs to take a `Call` parameter:

```
public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t)
```

It's possible the signatures of the methods have changed between versions of Retrofit, and that the tutorial is using an older version than you are. But I'm only speculating.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to diagnose: Just read the error message and understand it:

It says that you are trying to sublcass the `CallBack` interface, so you have to override all the methods it declares. But you are not; because you have not overrided right the `onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t)` method.

See? You missed to add the `call` parameter in the `onFailure` method.

Do not trust so tightly on tutorials; use it as a basis, not as a Gospel. Maybe that tutorial is based on a prior version of Retrofit. (Or it maybe contains mistakes).

Comment: [Godspell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godspell)? I think you mean gospel

Comment: Thank you. I'll be more careful with tutorials.

Comment: @Michael Right. Thank you.